# How to politely remove a coworker from an MMO guild

Tags: human-resources, colleagues

I am a guild leader in a popular MMO game and have various coworkers operating within guild space.  We are on the same plane in the workspace but in the online fantasy realm I am leagues ahead of the competition -- and everyone knows it.  However, my one coworker is, shall we say, lacking in almost all facets of MMO skillcraft and must be forthwith booted out of our prestigious guild.  We have a reputation to maintain.  How should I approach this?

Comment: Why did you invite them to play in the first place? Why not help them be a better player instead of giving them the boot?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with you firing him from the guild and him returning the favor to you in the real world once he gets promoted over you,

Comment: Is your guild playing something competitive with limited slots? Does he take the game very seriously?

Comment: *Must* be booted.  Prestige of your guild trumps harmony in the workplace?   Approach it just like you crush on the playing field.

Comment: Why do you play this with coworkers?

Comment: There is no Polite way to tell someone they are not good enough to play on the team.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really isn't specific to the workplace; it's just social dynamics.

Comment: @keshlam I think there's a core of a good question in here: "How do I handle a difficult social situation which could have implications for my professional relationships?"

Comment: @philipkendall: I'm not convinced there is a general answer to that one

Comment: I do think this is work-related, though somewhat tangentially. @PhilipKendall put it quite nicely. I believe the existing answers show that there are constructive solutions.

Comment: If you're too crappy of a leader to help this person get better then perhaps you should /gquit yourself :). I've played plenty of MMO myself and ran a guild from time to time, this post is nothing but a humblebrag.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Guilds are generally relatively short lived. Career influence and knowing people in the business lasts much longer. In short, do not kick this person from the guild.

Rather, have expectations that all guild members must abide by, and those that don't cut it are not invited to the raids or extreme guild events. Examples are a minimum item level requirement, or a minimum DPS. Players who are left out of the spotlight naturally seek to either improve their game or look to join other guilds.

Comment: "Guilds are generally relatively short lived" You have never been in any real MMO guild, have you? I know of several who exist for almost 10 years now...

Comment: Realm first clear of MC in vanilla. Guild died prior to the release of BC. Guilds that are elitist don't last; casual guilds however are a different story.

Comment: i'm also taking about guilds who had RFs during BC, Wrath, Cata and MoP and still exist. Guilds with elitism won't last, but you don't need to be elitist to achieve something. Though is certainly looks like the OP is more down the "elitist" route. However, you *can* make elistist guild also last for quite a while. just look at how many world top 100 guilds in WoW are quite old. The guilds who just do elitist but don't actually have anything to offer are the ones who quickly perish. i *do* agree that business relations and career influences are much more important than any guild!

Comment: A game is not just a game. Watch out when the ramifications of a player's actions spread and take root in other worlds, like the world of work.

Comment: @Polygnome Guilds that last for several years are outliers. The vast majority do not, especially without an explosion of popularity.

Comment: It’s just a game. Definitely not worth creating tensions with people who matter in real life.

Answer (score 9):

It seems you're someone with a lot of influence on the realm if you are one of the higher-ups in a prestigious guild. If you have a reputation to lose, you also have one to use.

You could therefore use your weight with more casual-play guilds to find your coworker a spot in one of those. Some of them might be happy to be owed a favour by one of the top people on the realm. Imagine they are short a tank for running a raid that you've cleared and are not running any more with your main character, so you have a free slot.

Then make the move to this other guild sound good to your co-worker. He'll have more people online and available at all times because the guild is larger and they are not always playing high-skill content on the hardest setting. They give away gear not in the way that advances the raid the fastest, but by general want and roll. They are nice people, and they want you to be in their guild.

If you can convince him those things will improve his situation in the game and he will thus have more fun, he will not think you wanted to get rid of him. He'll thank you instead, and he'll be more happy. It's a win-win situation.

Answer (score 4):

You must be in one of two situations:

1. He's filling up a slot when someone who performs much better wants to go instead.
2. There's not actually competition for slots, but other people are complaining he's underperforming.

In case #1, make up a reasonable minimum bar people need to hit.  Use concrete numbers from DPS or healing meters or stats.  Then tell everyone in the guild priority is given to people who hit the minimum.  There's no reason to kick him if he's not a problem socially.  If he wants, he can hang out, but not participate.  If he's tired of the rules, he can leave on his own, or try to improve.  If he complains, tell him everyone needs to hit the numbers in order to progress.

In case #2, tell the complainers that an underperformer is still better than an empty slot.  If they're so concerned that the guild looks bad, then they can leave.  You probably didn't want those people around anyways.

Answer (score 3):

If you really "need" to do this, you do it as simple and as factually as you can, making it clear that this is entirely unrelated to work.

> Hi, John.
>
> Unfortunately, we're going to have to ask you to leave our MMO guild. As you know, we're a guild that tries to maintain a high level of skill and you're not at that level at the moment. Sorry.
>
> For avoidance of doubt, this is nothing whatsoever to do with work. You are a fine worker and I hope that we can continue to have a excellent relationship during working hours.

Preferably, you do this in person. But you need to do it with a lot, lot, *lot* more tact than you show in your question, which makes you come across as a rather obnoxious person to say the least.

Comment: To be honest it's better to avoid that specially the lines that goes with works, very very few people on MMO don't make history after been kicked

Comment: You ought to also state that he will be welcomed back if he skills up